# Modify cell editor for different rows in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` with the following columns:

rowNumber | Element | Quantity

And a `JButton` that adds rows every time it's clicked. The column Element has a custom `JComboBox` cell editor that gets filled with elements from a database. However i need to do the following:

Suppose i have these elements in the `JComboBox` of the first row in my table: 
Element1 
Element2 
Element3

I select Element2 from the `JComboBox` in the first row and then I proceed to add another row.
This new row must not show Element2 any more in its `JComboBox`. And the previous (first) row must not show the Element selected in the second row and so on.

Comment: this look like as homework, for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue with [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) as [TableCellEditor in JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox)

Comment: What is the expected cardinality of the `Set<Element>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may help to know the expected cardinality of the `Set<Element>`. Accordingly, @mKorbel raises the important question of scalability, citing this related [discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2390422&tstart=0).  In that case, the question proposes a `List<DefaultCellEditor>`, when a *much* simpler renderer will do.

Here, a `CellEditor` can manage a `List<DefaultComboBoxModel<Element>>`, selecting the correct combo model for the row currently being edited and invoking `setModel()` on the editor component. As each new table row is added, the editor would add a new element to the `List` and adjust existing elements as required. I would expect the complexity to grow as *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, where *n* is the cardinality of the `Set`.

Comment: excelent description, maybe this way could be good example (without balast by Jörg) how to put different Items to the each of JComboBoxes in JTable, required Java7

Comment: @mKorbel: Much would depend on the source data. A `List<DefaultComboBoxModel>` should be backward compatible.

Comment: aaach thanks for answer, becasue I hate Generics ..., :-) out of memory for me :-)

Comment: Thank you! a CellEditor with a List of DefaultComboBoxModel will do the trick. Every time i add a new row i'll get a set of the current selected items and exclude them in the next JComboBox

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom CustomCellEditor like this.

```
final JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new CustomCellEditor(comboBox){
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
         DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = (DefaultComboBoxModel<String>) comboBox.getModel();
         model.removeAllElements();
         {//Add what you need according the row.
             model.addElement("X");
             model.addElement("Y");
             model.addElement("Z");
         }
         return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
   }
});
```

Comment: never do that add / modify or remove inside Renderer, this action is called on every mouse, keyboard, focus, JTable or TableModel events

Comment: @mKorbel: good point for `CellRenderer`, but `CellEditor` is called less often; it may be possible to cache previously constructed `ComboBoxModel` instances and update them as rows are added.

Comment: @trashgod [I saw similair question](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2390422&tstart=0), but I can't see difference betweens Editor and Renderer